# Form read only on default

Tags: permissions, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I created a form and I want the form is initially read-only, but especially a role can modify it, How do I this?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No programming is needed, just some AOT security entries.

And by default AX 2012 forms can be made read only, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147864/dynamics-ax-2012-commandbutton-insert-and-edit-by-form/25153883#25153883).

Create a [privilege](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731787.aspx) to view the form menu item and another privilege to maintain. 
Then create a duty containing the view privilege and another duty to maintain. 
Finally assign the duties to the respective roles.

[A good read here](http://daxing2012.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/ax2012-assigning-permissions-to-users-through-rolesprivileges-and-duties/).